# Websphere JaxWs Deployment

Tags: websphere, jax-ws

While Deploying JAX-WS, I am facing the following issues in Websphere 7(Fix Pack 17). I have already set `webservices-api-2.0.1.jar/jaxws-api-2.2.11.jar` in classpath in Websphere. Apart from that I have also tried by changing Parent Classloader policy `[Classes loaded with application class loader first ]` ..Please help..

```
Error Description :

00000009 http E WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/xml/ws/WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/xml/ws/WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processExceptions(RuntimeModeler.java:1262)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:982)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:744)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:504)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:335)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:100)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:127) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:487)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:283)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:158)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:577)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:303)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:179)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:152)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1707)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:380)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:610)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:726)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2048)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:441)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:951)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere 7.x supports JAX-WS 2.0.
You're trying to use JAX-WS 2.2.

The first thing you should do is to remove those two JAR files from the WebSphere directories. Placing your own custom JAR files in WebSphere's installation directories is generally a bad idea - WebSphere provides its own mechanisms for adding JARs to the server's runtime.

If you can settle for JAX-WS 2.0 - which is, overall, what I'd recommend; WebSphere isn't a huge fan of having people mess around with its supported specification levels - then you should remove those two JAR files altogether from your system and things should just work for you.

If you insist on JAX-WS 2.2, then you must be a brave one. Place these two JAR files in your EAR, set the EAR's classloading policy to PARENT_LAST, and work from there.